# How can I read from a text file and display matches without matching case?

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline

I'm having a small problem with my code, I'm reading a text file and displaying matches from user input. The only problem is that it's case sensitive, for example it wont display a match if the S in Steve is lower case because it is upper case in the text File. Here is the code I am using.

```
string name;

lstResult.Items.Clear();

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("../Name_Check.txt"))
{                
    while ((name = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {                    
        if (txtInput.Text == name)
        {                       
            lstResult.Items.Add(name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) instead of the `==`

For your example, this should work:

```
if (string.Equals(txtInput.Text, name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

(Instead of `if (txtInput.Text == name)`)

That assumes you want to use the current thread's current culture setting.

Or you can use the similar string.Equals() demonstrated by Daniel White.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 txtInput.Text.Equals(name, StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

You might have to change the last option depending on your culture.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested!)

```
string name;
lstResult.Items.Clear();
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("../Name_Check.txt"))
{
    while ((name = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (txtInput.Text.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            lstResult.Items.Add(name);
```